# Object key name overriding ruby on rails method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have the following ruby object 'charges' I am getting from the stripe api through the stripe-ruby gem

```
charges = Stripe::Charge.all(:count => 10, :offset => 0)
```

the following (which has been abbreviated) is returned with 10 charges

```
 #<Stripe::ListObject:0x3fcf852af17c> JSON: {"object":"list","count":828,"url":"/v1/charges","data":[{"id":"ch_.......
```

when I try to get the number of elements in the object by typing

```
charges.count
```

it returns 828 because that is the data associated with the key 'count' not the number of elements in the object (which should be 10)

How can I get the actual count?

Comment: I added some code above for clarity. 828 charges is the total number of charges on stripe.  With `:count` I am only requesting 10 and its only returning 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you want `charges.data.count` ? The object is not a standard Ruby Array, it is (as it states), a `Stripe::ListObject`, which has a `data` field.

Answer (score 1):

The [Stripe docs on this](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#list_charges) aren't that clear so I'll try to clear things up a bit based on empirical evidence. The `count` is the the total number of matches. The actual `Stripe::Charge` instances that you're looking for are in the `data` array:

```
list    = Stripe::Charge.all(:count => 10, :offset => 0)
charges = list.data
```

That puts the actual charge objects in the `charges` array and then you can ask the array how big it is:

```
list    = Stripe::Charge.all(:count => 10, :offset => 0)
charges = list.data

number_of_charges_returned = charges.count
```